# What jar-files needed for gilead with GWT?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, gilead

I do not find a good tutorial on integrating gilead for GWT with hibernate. I miss the step what jar files to include in my application.

Background:

There is some example source code at: 
    http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html to be found [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt_hibernate_gilead.zip), but I do not see that the same jars are used in the downloadable files from the [gilead download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gilead/files/) location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little trial and error resembles that I need the following jars:

**From gilead:**

- gilead-core-1.3.2.1839.jar
- gilead4gwt-1.3.2.1839.jar
- gilead-hibernate-1.3.2.1839.jar
- beanlib-hibernate-5.0.2beta.jar
- beanlib-5.0.2beta.jar

From Hibernate:

- cgib-full-2.0.2.jar
- log4j-1.2.9.jar

(or similar with a different version number).