# An RPC error While working with Hibernate In GWT Plotform

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I have been trying to use hibernate by fallowing the link [gwt with hibernate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate)  but i'm getting tha fallowing error but i'm quite sure my Hibernate part is Working properly
but when i'm trying to integrate hibernate with gwt it is giving the fallowing warning and data is not populating to client

```
    Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.SomeDTO' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.SomeDTO@f8dc0f
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:709)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:748)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:474)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some simple solution for this problem. as i'm using gwt platform, I'm taking the help of SomeResult class (that implements Result Interface) instead of creating a new pojo class and populate it to client i'm creating a parameterised constructor in SomeResult that holds the db data and simply sends it to client.

the following is some sample code

```
    public class SomeActionResult implements Result {
        private String str;
        private int myInt;

    public SomeActionResult(String str,
         int myInt){
    this.str=str;
    this.myInt=myInt;
    }
    //getters&setters

}
```

in hibernate i will be having a method that will return SomeActionResult(str,myInt)

```
public class MyDao{
    public static SomeActionResult getData(){
    //a hibernate query to retrieve the data and set them to str, myInt

    retrun new SomeActionResult(str,myInt);
    }
}
```

now in my SomeActionHandler class execute() method i'm calling getData() as following

```
public SomeActionResult execute(SomeAction action,ExecutionContext){

return MyDao.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hibernate-validator-*.jar must be in your war's WEB-INF/lib for this to work

Comment: thanks, yes just now i found it but still i'm getting the SerializationException even after fallowing the steps that are given in the link that i showed in my question i'm editin the question to show the error

Comment: A object which you used. did you implement IsSerializable? refer: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideSerializableTypes. i.e class SomeDTO implements Serializable, IsSerializable

Comment: I'm implementing Serializable Interface in my DTO Class, Do i need to implement IsSerializable also

Comment: Serializable classes must be included in a serialization policy, which is generated at compile time, while IsSerializable classes do not have that requirement.If you are working on pure gwt and DTO class not shared on web app or other app. so implement IsSerializable. and also Both Serializable & IsSerializable work

Comment: I've tried with both but still it is giving the same error, any suggestions, where i'm doing wrong

Comment: ok Now you have to add Gilead library to use Hibernate entities as you would expect in the client-side.

Comment: i think Gilead is some other approach[GWT with Hibernate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate) to integrate hibernate with gwt why do i really need to add that library, there are 3 approaches showed in this link i'm using the first approach and Gilead is the third

Comment: Becuase Hibernate generates proxy objects that use hibernate specific PersistentSet and PersistentList objects.
you need a objects which  emulated in the GWT emulated JRE.The correct way to solve this problem using the third party open source library hibernate4gwt (now named gilead):

Comment: could you please tell me the jar file names that i need to add

Comment: Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520428/what-jar-files-needed-for-gilead-with-gwt

Comment: Actually it's another issue[not a solution of asked question]. so now onwards try practice to ask new question for new query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your issue is fixed but check that your entities implement `Serializable` and have an empty constructor.

Comment: Yes i have both Serializable and empty constructor